# Dialogのスクリプトエディターで文章を修正するとエラーが発生

Tags: pepper

アプリ作成の基本を勉強中です。
Dialog/QiChatを試みているのですが、スクリプトエディターで文章を修正し再生するとDialogボックスがエラーになってしまいます。原因と対策を教えて頂きたくお願いします。
エラー内容は次の通りです。

```
[ERROR] behavior.box :init:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior72403904:/kaiwa_1: Error in box initialization:  LoadTopic::ALDialog
    A topic named /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior/kaiwa/kaiwa_jpj.top is already loaded
```

Comment: スタックオーバーフローへようこそ！ より質問を具体的にするため、可能であれば、参考にした資料へのURLや、どのように修正したかという情報を追記して頂けませんでしょうか？ 自分の質問は質問の下の「編集」から自由に書き直せますのでご利用ください。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージで検索すると、同様のエラーについて相談しているスレッドを見つけました。

- ["Dialog error"](https://community.ald.softbankrobotics.com/ja/node/4967) -- Softbank Robotics Community

ここに寄せられた回答によると「1つ前の Dialog をきちんと unload する前に load しているから生じているバグだ。多分あなたが書いたコードのバグだと思うが、もしコードを変にいじったりしてないなら内部的なバグかもしれない。詳細は実際のコードが無いと分からない。また、場当たり的だが、とりあえず[NAOqi](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAOqi)を再起動させると直ると思う。たとえばNAOqiにssh接続して `nao stop` をしたり、ウェブクライアント越しに止めれば良い」とのことです。

というわけで、unload を忘れていないか確認してみてください。これより詳しい回答は、コード片等が無いと私にはよく分からないです。